# Sencha Touch 2 itemTpl / XTemple Loop

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

So this is what I wish to achieve as an result

```
<div id=wrapper>
  <div id=columns>
    <div class=pin>
      <p><img src=image.jpg><br>somename</p>
    </div>
    <div class=pin>
      <p><img src=image2.jpg><br>somename2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my current itemTpl code in my Ext.DataView

```
itemTpl: '<div id=wrapper><div id=columns><tpl for=products><div class=pin><p><img src={image}><br>{name}</p></div></tpl></div></div>'
```

Currently my code return:

```
<div id=wrapper>
 <div id=columns>
   <div class=pin> 
     <p><img src=image.jpg><br>somename</p> 
   </div> 
 </div> 
</div> 
<div id=wrapper>
 <div id=columns>
   <div class=pin> 
     <p><img src=image2.jpg><br>somename2</p> 
   </div> 
 </div> 
</div>
```

My store/JSON looks like the following:

```
Ext.define('Sencha.store.HoardList',{
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    storeId: 'Plist',
    model:'Sencha.model.HoardList',
    title: 'My Collection',
    autoLoad: true,
    proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url : 'products.json',
            reader: {type: 'json', rootProperty:'products'}

        }

});
```

Json

```
{
    "success": true,
    "products": [
        {"name": "Product A",  "image": "images/product.jpg", "type": "shoe", "brand":"Nike", "color":"red"},

        {"name": "Product B",  "image": "images/product.jpg", "type": "short", "brand":"Nike", "color":"black"} 
    ]
}
```

The code obviously doesn't work the way I image. So my question is, how do one add wrapper ground the itemTpl code? Thanks a bunch!

Comment: "The code obviously doesn't work the way I image." Not so obvious to me, could you tell us what doesnt work.

Comment: Can you share code of your store and the sample data?

Comment: The code right now is spitting out:

`<div id=wrapper>
  <div id=columns>
    <div class=pin>
      <p><img src=image.jpg><br>somename</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id=columns>
  <div id=wrapper>
    <div class=pin>
      <p><img src=image2.jpg><br>somename2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>`

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Add more information on the question, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From whatever I understood from your question, give "columns"/"Wrapper" id to `list` or `Panel` containing list and itemTpl could be

```
'<tpl for="products">'+
    '<div class=pin><p><img src={image}><br>{name}</p></div>'+
'</tpl>'
```

this will repeat `<div class=pin>` for every list item

Comment: So are you suggesting, have a panel with `id: wrapper`, and inside with list with `id: column`, and then the tpl? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yes, but `pin` might not be direct children. BTW did it work?